# React animations

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, animation

I have 2 animations: one "entrance" and the other one "exit". On a click of a menu bar it opens a modal that contains an animation. But when i click again to close the "exit" animation is not resolving.

The objective is when i click on the CloseIcon i do the "exit" animation on the Box component.

After researching i came to the solution of using the following statement but it's only working for the "animation" and not working for "no-animation":

```
<Modal
          open={open}
          onClose={handleClose}
          className={open ? "animation" : "no-animation"}
        >
```

JS

```
import logo from "../media/logo.png";
import MenuIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Menu";
import { Button, Modal, Box } from "@mui/material";
import CloseIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Close";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import video from "../media/iguarias-video.mp4";
import InstagramIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Instagram";
import FacebookIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Facebook";
import tripadvisor from "../media/Orion_tripadvisor.svg";
const Menu: FC = () => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const handleOpen = () => setOpen(true);
  const handleClose = () => setOpen(false);
  return (
    <div className="menu">
      <div className="logo">
        <Link to="/">
          <img src={logo} alt="logo" />
        </Link>
      </div>

      <div>
        <div className="menu-opener" onClick={handleOpen}>
          <Button>
            <MenuIcon />
          </Button>
        </div>
        <Modal
          open={open}
          onClose={handleClose}
          className={open ? "animation" : "no-animation"}
        >
          <Box className="modal-menu">
            <div className="menu-video">
              <video autoPlay muted loop id="my-video">
                <source src={video} type="video/mp4"></source>
              </video>
            </div>
            <div className="menu-options">
              <div onClick={handleClose} className="cancel-icon">
                <Button>
                  <CloseIcon />
                </Button>
              </div>
```

CSS

```
.animation {
  animation-name: entrance;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}
.no-animation {
  animation-name: exit;
  animation-duration: 1s;
} 
@keyframes entrance {
  from {
    left: -4000px;
  }
  to {
    left: 0px;
  }
}

@keyframes exit {
  from {
    left: 0;
  }
  to {
    left: 4000px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say "not resolving", I'm assuming the modal just disappears instantaneously when you close it.

Consider what happens (with regards to mounting/unmounting) when you open or close the modal. When you open it, the Modal component and its contents exist in the DOM, and so there's no reason your animation shouldn't work. But if your `Modal` unmounts immediately on closing, it's removed from the DOM - so there's nothing to animate.

To solve the problem, you'll have to delay the "true" closing of `Modal` for one second; that way, the animation will be given time to complete.

You didn't say if `Modal` is your own custom component or if it comes from another library. But something like [react-responsive-modal](https://react-responsive-modal.leopradel.com/) could make your life easier as it handles animations for you and is accessible out of the box.

Comment: Yes, is exacly like you say: the modal disapears instantaneosly.

The modal is not custom, is from Material-ui. 
I will check it out react-responsive-modal

Comment: In that case MUI has you covered. Their Modal supports react-transition-group. You'll need to put a [Transition](https://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/transition) component directly inside the modal with the correct props (see the [MUI docs](https://mui.com/components/modal/) on Modal). Using react-responsive-modal is easier but using the built-in Modal of the component library you're already using is preferable.